# Spring Data Projection with QueryDSL Predicate not working

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am trying to use Spring Data projections with a QueryDsl predicate and when I exceute the query I get a 'java.util.NoSuchElementException'.

I've created the projected interface type and then pass then have the declaration in the repository as follows:

`Collection<Mini> findAllProjectedBy(Predicate predicate);`

My repository is declared as:

`public interface DeviceRepository extends CustomDefaultRepository<PersistableDevice, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<PersistableDevice>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QPersistableDevice> {`

If I don't use the predicate I have no trouble returning the projection.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue.